# ValueError: axes don't match array Pytorch Transpose operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pytorch

I'm trying to convert a PIL image to a torch Variable type. Here is the code for it:-

```
def preprocess_image(pil_im, resize_im=True):
    """
        Processes image for CNNs
    Args:
        PIL_img (PIL_img): PIL Image or numpy array to process
        resize_im (bool): Resize to 224 or not
    returns:
        im_as_var (torch variable): Variable that contains processed float tensor
    """
    # mean and std list for channels (Imagenet)
    mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406]
    std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]

    #ensure or transform incoming image to PIL image
    if type(pil_im) != Image.Image:
        try:
            pil_im = Image.fromarray(pil_im)
        except Exception as e:
            print("could not transform PIL_img to a PIL Image object. Please check input.")

    # Resize image
    if resize_im:
        pil_im = pil_im.resize((224, 224), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    im_as_arr = np.float32(pil_im)
    print(im_as_arr.shape)
    im_as_arr = im_as_arr.transpose(2, 0, 1)  # Convert array to D,W,H
    # Normalize the channels
    for channel, _ in enumerate(im_as_arr):
        im_as_arr[channel] /= 255
        im_as_arr[channel] -= mean[channel]
        im_as_arr[channel] /= std[channel]
    # Convert to float tensor
    im_as_ten = torch.from_numpy(im_as_arr).float()
    # Add one more channel to the beginning. Tensor shape = 1,3,224,224
    im_as_ten.unsqueeze_(0)
    # Convert to Pytorch variable
    im_as_var = Variable(im_as_ten, requires_grad=True)
    return im_as_var

original_image =  Image.open('blahblah.jpeg')
prep_img = preprocess_image(original_image)
```

I'm getting an error which says

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-08cf62156870> in <module>()
      1 original_image =  Image.open('blahblah.jpeg')
----> 2 prep_img = preprocess_image(original_image)

<ipython-input-22-ad146391ce9d> in preprocess_image(pil_im, resize_im)
    155     im_as_arr = np.float32(pil_im)
    156     print(im_as_arr.shape)
--> 157     im_as_arr = im_as_arr.transpose(2, 0, 1)  # Convert array to D,W,H
    158     # Normalize the channels
    159     for channel, _ in enumerate(im_as_arr):

ValueError: axes don't match array
```

I think there's some issue with the transpose operation. But I tested it out on another use-case and this worked perfectly. Not sure what's triggering this error.

Comment: I thought the `transpose()` method just rotated PIL images? [The docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your image does not have three dimensions, that means it is not an RGB image, but something else, e.g. a greyscale image, which would technically have a single channel, but NumPy automatically removes the singular dimension, so instead of having size *[H, W, 1]* it has size *[H, W]*.

Since you seem to be expecting RGB images, you can ensure that the images are in RGB mode, by converting them with PIL.

```py
pil_img = pil_img.convert("RGB")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured it out later!

Answer (score 0):

The line `pil_im = pil_im.resize((224, 224), Image.ANTIALIAS)` changes the array such that it has no third dimension (i.e. to grayscale).

The line `im_as_arr = im_as_arr.transpose(2, 0, 1)` assumes that the image has three dimensions (i.e. RBG).

You'll need to convert your image to RBG and change the resize dimensions before you call the transpose method; via-a-vis the method suggested by [Michael Jungo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61990757/13185080)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured it out :)